# When does a second order differential equation have two linearly independent Frobenius series solutions?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

When does a second order differential equation have two linearly independent Frobenius series solutions and when is there only one ?

**Specifically**

If $~x=0~$ is a regular point we use the Frobenius method. 
While solving indicial equation, three cases arise.

1. The roots of the indicial equation do not differ by an integer (i.e. fraction)
2. The roots of the indicial equation differ by an integer
3. The roots are same.

> So, can I conclude that second order differential equations always have two linearly independent series solutions?

**Example** $$x^2 y''+3\sin x y'+y=0$$ does not have two linearly independent Frobenius series solutions near $~x=0~$. This is because of the presence of $~\sin x~$. Am I right?

I made a search as far as I can. But I do not get any clear idea. Please help.

Comment: It is unclear what you are looking for. Can you edit your question and provide more detail?

Answer (score 2):

First to **the example**. The important part is not that the sine is present, but that $\sin x=x+x^3s(x^2)$ so that in the lowest orders you get the Euler-Cauchy equation $$x^2y''+3xy'(x)+y=0$$ with its solutions $$y(x)=x^{-1}(C+D\ln x)$$ due to the double root of its characteristic equation, which also is the indicial equation of the original DE. The terms that were removed constitute a perturbation, they contribute higher degree terms with and without logarithmic factor, but they will not remove the leading logarithmic term.

---

**In general** the Frobenius method for $$0=x^2y''(x)+xa(x)y'(x)+b(x)y(x),$$ $a,b$ at least continuous in $x=0$, will result in at least one Frobenius power series solution $y_1=\sum c_nx^{n+r}=x^rc(x)$. A second basis solution can be written, à la order reduction method, as $y_2=uy_1$. Inserted into the equation this gives 
$$
0=x^2[u''y_1+2u'y_1']+xa(x)u'y_1
\implies
\frac{u''}{u'}=-2\frac{y_1'}{y_1}-\frac{a(x)}{x}\\
u'(x)=\frac1{x^{a_0+2r}e^{\int \tilde a(x)dx}c(x)^2}
$$
where $a(x)=a_0+x\tilde a(x)$. To get a series solution for $y_2$, one needs that in the power series expansion $u'(x)=\frac1{x^{a_0+2r}}\sum d_nx^n$ no term integrates to yield a logarithm, that is, $a_0+2r-n\ne 1$ for any $n=0,1,2,...$ with $d_n\ne 0$. As $1-a_0-r$ is the other solution to the indicial equation $0=r(r-1)+a_0r+b_0$, the second solution is a power series whenever the roots do not have an integer difference. As by construction $d_0\ne 0$, in the case of double roots there will always be a logarithmic term. The other cases depend on the coefficients of the ODE.

---

Let's construct **examples for both cases for $r=\pm 1$**. Thus $a_0=1$, $b_0=-1$. Additionally specify that $a_1=-2$ and $y_1(x)=xc(x)$, with $c(x)=1+x+\frac{x^2}2+O(x^2)$ for the "unicorn" case $d_2=0$. Computing the minimal $b(x)$ gives the examples

1. $x^2y''+(x-2x^2)y'-(1+x-x^2)y=0$ for $d_1=0$ and
2. $x^2y''+(x-2x^2)y'-(1+x)y=0$ for $d_1\ne0$

*Example 2* has the coefficient recursion $[(n+r)^2-1]a_n-[2(n+r-1)+1]a_{n-1}=0$, which for $r=-1$ leads to the equations $0a_0=0$, $-a_1=-a_0$, $0a_2=a_1$ which is impossible for $a_0\ne 0$. $r=1$ has the equations $0a_0=0$, $3a_1=3a_0$, $8a_2=5a_1$, $15a_3=7a_2$ etc. leading to
$$
u'(x)=\frac1{x^3e^{-2x}(1+x+\frac58x^2+\frac{7}{24}x^3+...)^2}
=\frac{1 - \frac14x^2 + O(x^4)}{x^3}
$$
so that the second term is logarithmic in $u(x)=-\frac12x^{-2}-\ln x+O(x^2)$, giving 
$$
y_2(x)=-\ln(x)y_1(x)-\frac12x^{-1}-\frac12-\frac5{16}x+O(x^2).
$$

In *Example 1* the recursion is $[(n+r)^2-1]a_n-[2(n+r-1)+1]a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}=0$, which for $r=-1$ leads to the equations $0a_0=0$, $-a_1=-a_0$, $0a_2=a_1-a_0$, $3a_3=3a_2-a_1$ etc. which is solvable with two free coefficients $a_0,a_2$. The second case $r=1$ just replicates the first case with $a_0=0$ and $a_2=1$.